# Deploy Angular Backend API on Azure

Tags: html, angular, typescript, azure, azure-devops

I have made a backend API that connects to the sql that is also hosted on my azure account, however im not sure how to deploy this api on azure and make it available on there so that i can deploy my angular app to connect to this url instead of localhost.

Do you guys know of any tutorials or advice on how to deploy a backend typescript based api on to azure

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a new service in Azure that sounds like it fits your needs perfectly: [Azure Static Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/static/).

You can find a tutorial in the documentation: [Quickstart: Building your first static web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/getting-started).

> Azure Static Web Apps is a service that automatically builds and deploys full stack web apps to Azure from a GitHub repository.

and

> **What you can do with Static Web Apps**
>
> - Build modern JavaScript applications with frameworks and libraries like Angular, React, Svelte, Vue with an Azure Functions back-end.
> - Publish static sites with frameworks like Gatsby, Hugo, VuePress.
> - Deploy web applications with frameworks like Next.js and Nuxt.js.

Source: [What is Azure Static Web Apps Preview?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview)

**EDIT:**
In short, this service enables you to build a frontend using libraries like Angular, Vue and React, and also provides a way to build and deploy an API using JavaScript or TypeScript Azure Functions. You *could*, of course, do this manually, but if there's an integrated service for it...

As posted in the comments: I do **not** mean Static website hosting in Azure Storage, although that could work perfectly fine although it doesn't provide a solution for the API.

Comment: A stand alone Azure function should be the right service here as there are no mention of a front end.

Comment: @ffffff01 The question explicitly states "so that i can deploy my angular app to connect to this". And my solution uses Functions. So... 

Comment: Oooh, its to early  Sorry